# Custom approval workflow to auto start

Tags: workflow

I want to implement auto start of workflow when item is published. That is done. But when user publish document from ms office, solution is not working. Is there any way to achieve this.

I noticed OOTB approval workflow works from ms office as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are publishing the item to a document library open the library in SPD and Create a workflow for that library that initiate on Item Created and do with it as you would like.